# Is it possible to draw any 2D shape using just lines and arcs?

Tags: geometry

I've heard that using just a french curve and straight edge, an architect can sketch any 2-dimensional shape on his blueprint.

This makes me wonder: is there a theory that proves that any 2-dimensional closed shape can be represented as a finite sequence of lines and arcs joined that their ends?

Comment: No, but as a sufficiently good approximation

Comment: You'd need to be more mathematically precise about what you mean by "2-dimensional shape" and "sequence of lines and arcs."  For instance, shapes with fractal boundaries like the [Koch Snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) would be impossible to physically draw.

Comment: @icurays1 What term do I use to describe the joined segments of a flat shape?

Comment: @VilhelmGray I'm not sure what you mean by "joined segments."  I think the most appropriate mathematical definition here would be "2D regions with rectifiable boundary," which means the boundary of the shape has finite length.

Comment: Cool question. I always wondered that and how the french curve was supposed to be used.

Comment: You can't draw a parabola with a finite number of line segments and circular arcs, if that's what you mean...

Comment: Forgive me, I'm coming from a programming background, so the best way I can describe the shapes is: those which can be draw via turtle graphics. That is, shapes created by a single cursor which moves across a plane and arrives at its initial location without inhabiting a previously inhabited point (i.e. the trailing line does not intersect itself).

Comment: In the early days of computer graphics, specifically in the age of MacPaint, I needed to produce a picture of the exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$ over an interval extending some distance (I don't remember exactly how far) to either side of $0$. MacPaint could produce only lines and ellipses (and freehand drawings, which if done by me would be disasters). I found that I could use an arc of a circle and get a quite passable-looking picture of the exponential function.  I think the key here and in your architects' drawings is that "passable" depends on human perception capabilities.